# How to use DbContext in multi-threaded app

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have an EF Core website that is set up in the typical way.  This has worked fine.

However, I added a Controller Method that gets hit several times per second and when there are multiple active threads, EF throws an exception.  If the requests are a few seconds apart, then it works fine.

I have tried debugging this, but I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Here are the details:

The requests are coming from a single page app, and they are all the same connection.  If there is only one request, it works fine.  But if there are two requests, then the exception is thrown.

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException
>     HResult=0x80131508
>     Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>     Source=System.Data
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckHeaderIsReady(Int32 columnIndex, Boolean permitAsync, String methodName)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__12.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__31`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.d__31`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.d__11.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<Aggregate_>d__6`3.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Traken.Data.Repositories.LookupListItemRepository.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Dev\Traken.app\Traken.5\Dev\Traken\Data\Repositories\LookupListItemRepository.cs:line 38

The repository which is use:

`services.AddScoped<LookupListItemRepository, LookupListItemRepository>();`

I have also tried `AddTransient` but I get the same error.

`services.AddTransient<LookupListItemRepository, LookupListItemRepository>();`

The DbContext:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(optionsBuilder =>
{
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
});
```

The controller

```
[HttpGet("{tableName}")]
public async Task<List<LookupListItem>> GetLookupTableAsync(string tableName) => await this._repository.List(tableName);
```

The Repository

```
public async Task<List<LookupListItem>> List(string tableName)
{
    return await this._dbContext.LookupTables.FromSql(
                    $@"{SqlStrings.SP.GetLookupTable} 
                    @tableName = {tableName}"
                ).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by setting the repository to `AddTransient`, instead of `AddScoped`

```
services.AddTransient<LookupListItemRepository, LookupListItemRepository>();
```

and setting the lifetime of the context to `Transient`.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(optionsBuilder =>
{   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

See Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async

```
public async Task<List<Blog>> GetBlogsAsync()
{
    using (var context = new BloggingContext())
    {
        return await context.Blogs.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: While using transient lifetime should resolve any such issues, it should not be necessary.  But nor is it particularly harmful.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft If it is not necessary, then what does this mean?  That there is an issue that should be reported so it can be fixed?

Comment: Yes if you have a simple repro, edit your question to include it.  Everything in a request is _supposed_ to run sequentially and so a request-scoped DbContext would never be accessed by two threads at the same time.